# What does it mean when the jvm address of an object is 0?

Tags: java, memory, hadoop, jvm

I have an object, Mutation, that I have "new"ed. But when it prints out with toString(), the object says Mutation@0. That doesn't seem good to me. What might that mean?

Comment: The `0` is not an address. It is the hashCode() which has little to do with an address other than looking similar because it is in hexi-decimal. Even Object.hashCode() is a value stored in the header which doesn't changed even when the object is moved between generations (and thus has a different memory address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code of `Mutation`, a good chance is you'll find this in there:

```
@Override public int hashCode() { 
   //TODO: implement this properly!
   return 0; 
}
```

The default implementation of `toString()` just reports this fact that `hashCode` returned 0.

Comment: Mutation is OP's own object I guess.If I'm wrong, Can you please attach that API link ??

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Yes, I am assuming it it his own class. The point of my answer is pointing to the source of the problem.

Comment: +1 .Ah..That Source Code term drive me in to crazy,and wanted to see the API immediately :)

Comment: It's actually not my class. It's a part of the Accumulo API. So I have no way of implementing a proper hashCode. How can I then compare 2 Mutation objects??

Answer (score 3):

That is Unsigned hexadecimal representation

[As per Docs of toString() method in Object class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

That `zero`  in the sense the Hashcode not yet calculated.

[Source Code:](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Object.java#Object.toString%28%29)

```
   public String toString() {
237        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
238    }
```